# Print fields being browsed on the screen

Tags: filemaker

I need to write a FM script which print one field of the records being browsed on the screen and separated by commas.However, I do not know how to select the records being currently browsed and am not able to find it in the documentation (the lack of the good keyword could be the problem).

Thank you!

Comment: It seems like you're asking two questions: how do I separate values by commas and how do I print records currently being browsed. Is that right?

Comment: Do you mean you want to print all values in a single field from multiple records, all in one row separated by commas? This is not going to be exactly simple. Could you explain why you need this? Also, please state the version you are using.

Comment: I am using FM Pro 13. This is to allow a simple copy & paste to an e-mail client of e-mail addresses. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to create a list of all values for one field in the Found Set. FileMaker 13 introduced the `List of` Summary type, which makes this pretty easy:

First, create a Summary field, say `FoundAddresses`. Make it a List of your e-mail address field. This field will contain a return-delimited list of the e-mail addresses in the Found Set.

Second, create a Calculation field, say `FoundAddressesCommaDelimited`. Make it the following text Calculation:

```
Substitute (
   GetSummary ( FoundAddresses ; FoundAddresses ) ;
   ¶ ; ", "
)
```

This will substitute all of the returns in `FoundAddresses` for comma-space.